# data is not getting stored in database

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to store the record for following DAC into database in ContractMaint graph extension.

```
public class ContractAndContractTerminationReason : IBqlTable
{
    #region ContractAndContractTerminationID
    [PXDBIdentity(IsKey = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Contract And Contract Termination ID")]
    public virtual int? ContractAndContractTerminationID { get; set; }
    public abstract class contractAndContractTerminationID : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region ContractID
    [PXDBInt()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Contract ID")]
    [PXDBDefault(typeof(Contract.contractID))]
    [PXParent(typeof(Select<Contract, Where<Contract.contractID, Equal<Current<ContractAndContractTerminationReason.contractID>>>>))]
    public virtual int? ContractID { get; set; }
    public abstract class contractID : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region ContractTerminationReasonID
    [PXDBInt()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Reason")]
    [PXParent(typeof(Select<
            ContractTerminationReason,
            Where<ContractTerminationReason.contractTerminationReasonID, Equal<Current<ContractAndContractTerminationReason.contractTerminationReasonID>>>>))]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<
            ContractTerminationReason.contractTerminationReasonID,
            Where<ContractTerminationReason.contractID, Equal<Current<Contract.templateID>>>>), DescriptionField = typeof(ContractTerminationReason.description))]
    public virtual int? ContractTerminationReasonID { get; set; }
    public abstract class contractTerminationReasonID : IBqlField { }
    #endregion
}
```

Here in the ContractMaint graph extension I have created following view.

```
public PXSelect<ContractAndContractTerminationReason> ContractAndContractTerminationReasons;
```

And when user selects value and click on OK on popup panel, it gets inserted in the database. Here is the full code snippet of 'Terminate' method I have overridden.

```
public delegate void TerminateDelegate();
        [PXOverride]
        public void Terminate(TerminateDelegate baseMethod)
        {
            Contract contractTemplate = PXSelect<Contract, Where<Contract.contractID, Equal<Current<Contract.templateID>>>>.Select(Base);
            bool isContractTerminationReasonEnabled = contractTemplate.GetExtension<ContractExt>().UsrEnableTerminationReason == null ? false : (bool)contractTemplate.GetExtension<ContractExt>().UsrEnableTerminationReason;
            if (isContractTerminationReasonEnabled)
            {
                if (SpecifyTerminationReason.AskExt(
                delegate
                {
                }) == WebDialogResult.OK)
                {
                    using (var ts = new PXTransactionScope())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            ContractAndContractTerminationReasons.Insert(contractAndContractTerminationReason);
                            ContractAndContractTerminationReasons.Cache.IsDirty = true;
                            Base.Actions.PressSave();
                            ts.Complete();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            PXTrace.WriteError(ex);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //baseMethod();
        }
```

I can see the code's been executed. And there's no error too. But it's not getting stored in the database.

Just as a note following is the PXFilter view for my popup panel that I use to select the ReasonID:

```
public PXFilter<ContractTerminationReason.ContractAndContractTerminationReason> SpecifyTerminationReason;
```

Thank you.

Comment: do you get any value on the return of ContractAndContractTerminationReasons.Insert? if its null then the insert is not occurring. You can also look at ContractAndContractTerminationReasons.Cache.Inserted before persisting (PressSave) to see if the value is there for insert. IsDirty should be set to true automatically. If its not then this would be the start of your issue.

Comment: Hi. The value is being returend from ContractAndContractTerminationReassons.Insert.
https://imgur.com/a/TBVHL3D

And I also see the values in ContractAndContractTerminationReasons.Cache.Inserted.

https://imgur.com/GnxWIVK

Though, the weird part is I can see two items in Cache Inserted even after I clear cache 
`ContractAndContractTerminationReasons.Cache.Clear();`
after completion of Transaction.

Comment: strange. You could remove the use of PXTransaction unless you are working with another graph which it doesn't look like you are. Can you confirm the ContractAndContractTerminationID in your database is setup as an identity field?

Comment: Yeah. ContractAndContractTerminationID is the primary key and as an identity field. Actually, I have had ContractID and ContractTerminationReasonID as a composite key but since that didn't work. I had added ContractAndContractTerminationID.

https://imgur.com/a/CEE5B9g

Comment: strange. Can you provide a simplified package with code to me and I can review more? Nothing is standing out the way you have it.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jdTb0DSfLmBguL7xgJAKNNLokuDumt0t/view?usp=sharing

Here is the link to the customization.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing your code I would drop the public DAC property and use a view/cache for storing data.

In your graph extension you have the following which I don't see you needing. Using a view/cache is the preferred method.

```
ContractAndContractTerminationReason contractAndContractTerminationReason = new ContractAndContractTerminationReason();
```

As a result you can remove the `ContractAndContractTerminationReason_ContractTerminationReasonID_FieldUpdated` event and just use the filter current values (assuming they have the values you need).

In its most simplest form this works. The project you shared didn't have the page entries or the table entries in it so I removed the panel prompt from the sample. This will save the records.

```
public class ContractMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ContractMaint>
{
    public PXSelect<ContractAndContractTerminationReason> ContractAndContractTerminationReasons;

    public delegate void TerminateDelegate();
    [PXOverride]
    public virtual void Terminate(TerminateDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        var newRow = new ContractAndContractTerminationReason
        {
            ContractID = Base.Contracts.Current.ContractID,
            ContractTerminationReasonID = 2 //SpecifyTerminationReason.Current.ContractTerminationReasonID
        };

        ContractAndContractTerminationReasons.Insert(newRow);
        ContractAndContractTerminationReasons.Cache.Persist(PXDBOperation.Insert);
        ContractAndContractTerminationReasons.Cache.Clear();

        baseMethod();
    }
}
```

Is the code you are using prompt for a panel? For a Filter I typically create a filter DAC and not use the same DAC to perform updates. Maybe this is causing your issue.

One problem you will run into is you are persisting the record when the baseMethod might not complete and not mark the contract as terminated. As a result your table will have a terminated reason without the contract being in a terminated state. Just something to watch for.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your suggestion. And after your suggestion this is how my code looks like. 

I don't think I can use PXSelect for the Popup's view, so I have used PXFilter.
And I also put the base method before my custom code. (Though it is comment for now during development.)

https://imgur.com/a/N9yb4j8

But, sadly the data is not being stored in the database.

Comment: PXFilters are not persisted. You need a PXSelect. I removed the PXFilter in my example to remove all code i didn't use, however for your panel and persist you will need both the PXFilter AND PXSelect. You insert and persist against the PXSelect view.

Comment: That's why I have had PXFilter and PXSelect. PXFilter for popup panel and PXSelect for inserting the record. And, I created a new object of DAC (ContractAndContractTerminationReason) and tried to save using PXSelect. But, still it's not working.

Comment: Try to use a different DAC for your filter (just copy past the other dac and give it a new name). The last screen shot only had the use of filter and that will not work. Try to split out the filter and select as "different" dacs

Comment: That worked perfectly. I created another DAC named ContractAndContractTerminationReasonFilter with the columns ContractID and ContractTerminationReasonID. And it worked. Thank you so much for the idea.

Comment: No problem. I typically create a filter DAC for filters anyhow. Filters are never hitting the database so it doesnt matter how the DAC is setup or if that name exists as a table. Glad you got it working.